How To Fix Google Sheets Send Text On Edit bot
I am currently struggling to write a program that automaticaly sends out an email when the value of a cell changes from 0 to 1, and cant seem to get it to work.
I want it to read the value of a specific cell on edit, see if the cells value has changed, then run an automated email send. I keep getting

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range').

function onEdit (e)
  const specificSheet = "SHEET"   // for example
  const specificCell = "CELL"       // for example

  let sheetCheck = (e.range.getSheet().getName() == specificSheet)
  let cellCheck = (e.range.getA1Notation() == specificCell)

  if (!(sheetCheck && cellCheck)) {
    return
  }
  else {

function sendText() {
    var EmailTo = "EMAIL A";
    var EmailTo = "EMAIL B";
    var subject = "Automated Spreadsheet Access Bot";
    var body = "TEXT";

  MailApp.sendEmail(EmailTo, subject, body);
}
}


Here's something you can try:
const specificSheet = 'example';
const specificCell = 'D5';

function sendMailEdit(e) {

  var sheetCheck = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  var cellCheck = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var value = e.value;
  var lastValue = e.oldValue;

  if(sheetCheck === specificSheet && cellCheck === specificCell && lastValue == 0 && value == 1) {

    var email = 'email@gmail.com';
    var subject = 'Subject of Email';
    var body = 'Email Body';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);

  }

}


Hi Kreeszh, I tried this, but I still cant get it to work. It still returns a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')." If it helps at all the name of the sheet is SHEET 1 and the cell is Z950. I think It's just I am not writing it in properly.
-Thanks

Are you testing the code within the editor itself using the run button? If you do that, e won't have a defined value, and cause an error.

I have been testing the code through the sheet itself, but it is not triggering. I am unsure why.

Change the name of the function, so it goes through the permissions again. Don't use onEdit.

const specificSheet = "SHEET1";
const specificCell = "Z950";
function sendText() {
var sheetCheck = range.getSheet().getName();
var cellCheck = range.getA1Notation();
var value = value;
var lastValue = oldValue;
if(sheetCheck === specificSheet && cellCheck === specificCell && lastValue == 0 && value == 1) {
var EmailTo = "25laneb@student.tcc.nsw.edu.au";
var subject = "TEST 01";
var body = "THIS IS A TEST";
MailApp.sendEmail(EmailTo, subject, body);

}
}
My code now looks like this, It still doesn't work. What have I done wrong?

Your original code was using the onEdit function, do you still have it set up that way?  You should change the name of the function and install it to the spreadsheet as an onEdit trigger manually. This is because the onEdit function is a special reserved function that has restrictions on what actions it can perform. You can find details here about this topic: Simple Triggers . Let me know if this clears it up.
